# Getting insufficient memory available in the buffer pool

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to trim out most data across a few dozen tables in a copy of a database.  This is an ad hoc need I'm performing on a local machine running **SQL Server 2008R2 Standard SP1**.  Tables are notable but not *tremendously* large, with the larger ones at tens of millions of records.

When running large DELETEs, I'm getting an "insufficient memory available in the buffer pool" error.  I can see physical memory continue growing without any indication of releasing memory.

I have set recovery to simple, and have tried chunking the deletes using rowcount to throttle.  At the end of each chunk I see no evidence of the memory being released.  Next attempt was to wrap in an explicit transaction, with no difference in the outcome.  I've also had no luck with

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL')
```

Does anyone have suggestions around where else I might free up the memory mid process?  Because this is a rare, ad hoc need being done on a local machine, I'm okay with some choices that might otherwise be not a best practice for ongoing production scenarios.  I'd like to steer clear of rewriting all sorts of involved rewriting to a "perfect" solution, e.g. dropping constraints and indexes, then rebuilding after truncating and adding data.

Comment: Have you set the maximum memory for SQL Server? It's not going to give up memory once it claims it either way.